# postgres request large database data table

Tags: java, mongodb, postgresql

I have a Postgres data base in which I store every minute five or more measures, so at the end of the month I have a really big table, and when I try to display the measurements in my web application it take time to display the charts due to the data base request.

Some collegues told me to convert the data base from postgres to mongodb.
So I want to know if I'am doing it wrong ? is there a better way to store and find data to display charts with heavy quantity of data ? And if mongodb is a better solution ?

Comment: What you are looking for is called a time-series database. MongoDB can be used for that. This blog post and its links offer some good information http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will check this blog.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the underlying database system, I would try to find out where the time complexity lies. If it is the database, try to tune performance by creating appropriate indexes, or to access only that data that you really need by using stored procedures that allow you to customize your request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will do searchs for how to create indexes and stored procedures and see if it reduces the time for requests.